# How to perform optimal number distributions

Tags: math, algebra

The program I am working on has the following positive integers:

```
TL = L1*C1 + L2*C2
TL = h1*r1 + h2*r2
hMAX>=r1>r2
```

TL, L1, C1, L2, C2 and hMAX are known. I need to determine h1, r1, h2 and r2 as to:

1. Minimize r1 + r2.
2. Minimize the difference between h1 and h2.

h1 and h2 must be an algebraic combination of L1 and/or L2. Meaninig:

```
h1 = a*L1 + b*L2
```

with a and b being integers >=0. h2 and r2 may be zero.

I can't seem to find a solution that will yield good results consistently for all L1, C1, L2, C2 inputs.

I tried the following:

```
h1 = min(int(hMAX/L1), C1)*L1
r1 = int(L1*C1/h1)
r2 = math.ceil(TL/hMAX)-r1
h2 = (TL-h1*r1)/r2
```

This worked for several inputs, but I came across certain cases that broke this, such as:

```
L1 = 106
C1 = 5
L2 = 96
C2 = 2
hMAX = 220
```

Comment: What does “h1 and h2 must be an algebraic combination of L1 and/or L2” mean? Do you mean a linear combination, h1 = j1•L1 + k1•L2 for some integers j1 and k1, and similarly for h2?

Comment: Minimizing r1+r2 and minimizing the difference between h1 and h2 (do you mean |h1−h2|?) are two goals. How do you reconcile them, what do you do when there is one answer that minimizes r1+r2 and a different answer that minimizes |h1−h2|?

Comment: Correct, a linear combination with j1, k1 integers >=0.

Solutions that minimize r1+r2 are preferred over solutions that minimize |h1-h2|

Comment: Use an integer programming solver. Solve the problem a first time with all your constraints and objective "minimize r1+r2". Call R the optimal value of this objective. Then add the constraint "r1+r2=R" to the problem, and solve the problem once more, with objective "minimize |h1-h2|".

Comment: For the second part, get rid of the absolute value: [How to write an absolute value expression in linear programming?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1597435/how-to-write-an-absolute-value-expression-in-linear-programming)